# Proposal: Merge tags: manual-testing and manual

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

By far https://sqa.stackexchange.com/tags/manual-testing/info (588 questions) is more common than https://sqa.stackexchange.com/tags/manual/info (16 questions). Seems like the latter should be merged into `manual-testing`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An excellent idea.

Done and done. Merged and mapped. Thanks!

Note I didn't add [status-complete](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-complete) because that is for feature requests and bug fixes. :-)